# Is safe to consider sequential operation on file system to occur in the same order?

Tags: linux, windows, generics, file-io, filesystems

If I perform several operation on a File System, i.e: I write data on File1.txt, after I write data on File2.txt and after I write something on File3.txt, if something goes bad like a system crash or a power failure, can I be sure of that: if File2.txt writting wasn't persisted on disk, this neither occurred on File3.txt?

Of course before writing to another file, I flush the current one.

Just to show a sample case scenario: I add data continuously to File1.txt and at some moments I write some checkpoint data on a File2.txt to be able to recover the writing of File1.txt in case of a system failure. Of course I need when I write the checkpoint, to be sure the data I wrote on File1 are persisted on the disk, otherwise the checkpoint information would be wrong.

I would know this for all the platforms, Windows, Linux and MacOS.

Comment: There are no such guarantees. Even if hardware manufacturers promise to service flush requests before returning control, they will generally lie to you.

Comment: Yes I know I cannot be sure flush is enough, but at least I want to know if I can trust hardware commit data in the same order I requested commit. It's not important for me how many data aren't committed and in case of failure, I just need to be sure if the first write hasn't been committed,  netiher the second has been.

Comment: @Eghes You can only trust enterprise storage hardware. Mostly. Sometimes not even then. For example, I had a laptop SSD recover from powerloss with old copies of some blocks, with other blocks checksum not matching because they were written later, with checksums for the committed blocks that had reverted. Had to restore the btrfs filesystem from backup.